# Questions regarding reCaptcha v3

Tags: recaptcha-v3

We wish to implement reCAPTCHA v3 within our website, however we have some doubts:
All internal corporate networks are seen as a single IP address so can all browsing be considered a bot? Is there a risk of an internal blocking?

Also, what are the remedies if the score deduced by reCAPTACHA is 0.1 for example? Do we have the hand to change the score of a user?

Thank you for your help !

D.

Comment: Do you need the CAPTCHA for users that access the site from within your corporate network? If those users can be “trusted” not to do anything shady, then perhaps the better alternative would be to implement the CAPTCHA for access from IP addresses outside your network only …?

Comment: _“Also, what are the remedies if the score deduced by reCAPTACHA is 0.1 for example? Do we have the hand to change the score of a user?”_ - no, I don’t think there is any way to do that. You can only decide what you want to _do_ based on that score - so you could also say, a 0.1 is “acceptable” when the request comes from within your network, and not if from outside. But whether having the CAPTCHA for users from within your network makes that much sense then in first place, rather doubtful. So I would go with not using the CAPTCHA for those, if that is a viable option.

Comment: Thank you misorude for your expertise! It's very clear.

I did not know that we could only select the external IP addresses! Is it easy to implement?

Also, how does one decide the score score that is acceptable? Is the method easy to implement?

Comment: The requesting IP can be found in the server or enviroment variables - in PHP for example, it should be in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` (should be, because depending on details of the network setup, whether proxies are involved etc., that might vary), other server-side languages provide access to in other ways, go research it if necessary.

Comment: _“Also, how does one decide the score score that is acceptable?”_ - that is something you basically have to figure out for yourself. Google recommends to start with a 0.5 threshold, and see what results that gets you, https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#score If you are getting consistently lower values for your target audience, then you might need to modify that accordingly.

Comment: Thank again misorude !

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible, when a user misses reCAPTACHA v3, to make automatically appear reCAPTACHA v2? Or if there is an alternative path that we could make him do? Because in my company, some people have very low scores and are considered to bots :/